# yii2 search of one grid view is affecting other gird views

Tags: search, yii2, dataprovider

I have multiples Grid Views in index page, Every Grid view (say: pending records Grid view, completed records Grid view, cancelled records Grid view, ... ) has same columns (e.g: name, number, location, ... ) and each of them is having its own search/filter row and every Grid view is making an Pjax call for search.

Until it is making Pjax call every thing is fine, but in some cases (I don't know exact) the page is refreshing and the search is applied for all the grid views (This is the issue).

Please give me the solution for this.

My previous issue was, Each and every Grid view is also having pagination, when I use to click on one Grid view's pagination it was affecting the other Grid view's pagination also and the solution is, I have used different pageParam :

```
'pagination' => [
    'pageParam' => 'ConfirmedPackage',
],
```

Is there any similar type of solution for search/filter of the Data Provider?

As after page reload it is taking same class name in the url for searching the grids.

Thank you.

Comment: add id to `gridview`.

Comment: Adding id to gridview doesn't help @gamitg

Comment: so, use pjax with id for different gridview.

Comment: Are all the gridviews replaced with the same result or are they all being individually filtered i.e. results are different but filtered by search form?

Comment: On page load each gridview will have its own and unique data (but columns are same), when I'm trying to search in a particular grid all the other grids also searching for the same thing and show result as per their own data.

At present I have removed the Grid wise search and using a Search form as a common search for all the grids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mention in my question that the problem is due to the same class name (in the url), I was using the same class for all the search functions in the search model and when I tried with different classes it worked perfectly :).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for what is happening is that you are using the same class for all your search models. This, in turn, leads to filter fields having identical names, something like `ProductSearch[description]`. Fortunately, there is a solution.

You should define your own [`formName()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#formName%28%29-detail) method in your model. By default, it returns class name. For you, it should return different names for each model instance you're using. This way you'll get something like `ProductSearch1[description]`, `ProductSearch2[description]`, etc.

I suggest you define a public variable in your class (for example, `formName`), initialize it when you create your model instance, and return it in `formName()` method.

Here's a concrete example.

```
class ProductSearch extends ProductSearch
{
    public $formName = null;

    public function formName()
    {
        if (null == $this->formName) {
            return parent::formName();
        } else {
            return $this->formName;
        }
    }

    //other class attributes and methods
}
```

Here's how you use this model:

```
$model1 = new ProductSearch();
//will generate default names like ProductSearch[somefield]

$model2 = new ProductSearch(['formName' => 'MyProductForm']);
//will generate names like MyProductForm[somefield]

$model3 = new ProductSearch();
$model3->formName = 'MyProductForm';
//a different way to initialize the model
//will also generate names like MyProductForm[somefield]
```

Comment: Beowulfenator you got my point. Your answer may solve my problem, but I'm a beginner in YII and I'm confuse how to change the class name with a method. But you gave me a hint that, different class name will solve the problem.
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You can't change a class name with a method. I'll update my answer.